# Google now cannot display cards because of low storage space

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, internal-storage, google-now, motorola-moto-g2

My android phone has 5.5gb of internal storage and I have used around 3.9. I have the rest of the apps on a SD card set as adoptable storage . Google now says it cannot display cards because of low storage space. Why is that?

Comment: I've had the same, with cleared cache, and ~15GB free; not sure what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

Just clearing the cache didn't fix the problem. But restarting the phone afterwards solved it.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is becasue of cache files go in settings>storages>cache data and clear them.